# Removing the words DateTimeIndex from a list of dates

Tags: python, pandas, list, datetime

I have a multiple list of dates in a pandas dataframe in this format:

```
col1                       col2
1                          [DatetimeIndex(['2018-10-01', '2018-10-02', 
                           '2018-10-03', '2018-10-04'],
                            dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

I would like to take off the words `DatetimeIndex` and `dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D'` and turn the list into a set. The format I would be looking for is:
`{'2018-10-01', '2018-10-02', '2018-10-03', '2018-10-04}`

Comment: Can you convert to a list using `x = list(your_variable)`?

Comment: `DatetimeIndex` has a `tolist()` method

Comment: Will either of these work if these lists are in a dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

Pandas is not designed to hold collections within series values, so what you are looking to do is **strongly discouraged**. A much better idea, especially if you have a consistent number of values in each `DatetimeIndex` series value, is to join extra columns:

```
D = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2018-10-01', '2018-10-02', '2018-10-03', '2018-10-04'],
                     dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1], 'col2': [D]})

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('col2').values.tolist()))

print(df)

   col1          0          1          2          3
0     1 2018-10-01 2018-10-02 2018-10-03 2018-10-04
```

---

If you *really* want a `set` as each series value, you can do so via `map` + `set`:

```
df['col2'] = list(map(set, df['col2'].values))

print(df)

   col1                                               col2
0     1  {2018-10-01 00:00:00, 2018-10-02 00:00:00, 201...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
set(index_object.tolist())
```

I suspect this will return you a set of timestamp objects rather than strings so depends on your use case whether this is something you want

if it's the strings you want you can modify the code as follows:

```
set(index_object.dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").tolist())
```

For your specific format (which I don't necessarily approve of!) you can try this:

```
import itertools
string_lists = col2.apply(lambda x: x.dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").tolist())
unique_set = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(string_lists.tolist()))
```

Comment: Can I do this in a dataframe without a loop?